# passing a jstl list to a javascript function under onclick event

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

as the title says. 
I got an object gotten from the Controller, on which one of its attributes is a List.
Now i want to pass this List to an external file javascript function.

Something like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="showAuthorityOverlay(<c:out value='${userDetail.grantedAuthorityList}'/>)">[SHOW AUTHORITY]</a>
```

Now the value passed to the javascript is something like this:

[ADMIN_USER, COMMON_USER]

So when i click in that link, i get a javascript error saying:

ADMIN_USER isn't defined.

What's wrong here? is it taking the ADMIN_USER and COMMON_USER as variable names? or what? Kinda weird.

Tried even making an inner script in my jsp to get the list like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    function showAuthorityOverlay() {
          var obj = "<c:out value='${userDetail.grantedAuthorityList}'/>";
          sendToExternalJSFile(obj);
    }
</script>
```

But still getting the same results. Looks like the values aren't passing correctly through as a List parameter.

Comment: The generated JavaScript will look like `showAuthorityOverlay([ADMIN_USER, COMMON_USER])`. Is this right, or maybe should be `showAuthorityOverlay('[ADMIN_USER, COMMON_USER]')`?

Comment: Yeah but how can I achieve that? Tried but is hard because of the quotes.
<a href="#" onClick="<c:out value=\'${userDetail.grantedAuthorityList}\'/>">[SHOW AUTHORITY]</a>

Comment: You can do it at server side appending the `'` when building the `String` or using an EL function to add the `'` symbol from that input. I would recommend changing this at server side.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did now :) Thanks! it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSTL code is executed at server-side. In this case, instead of being used to generate HTML, it's also being used to generate JavaScript code (which is perfectly valid).

The `toString()` method of your list, which `<c:out>` calls, returns the toString representation of every Java object in the list, separates them by commas, and surrounds them with brackets. The end result being

```
[ADMIN_USER, COMMON_USER]
```

The generate HTML + JavaScript is then downloaded by the browser, which interprets the JavaScript code:

```
showAuthorityOverlay([ADMIN_USER, COMMON_USER]);
```

This happens (by accident) to be syntaxically correct JavaScript code. It means: call the function `showAuthorityOverlay()` with a JavaScript array as argument. The array contains the value of the two JavaScript variables `ADMIN_USER` and `COMMON_USER`.

I assume that you in fact want a JavaScript array of strings instead, which should be written as `['ADMIN_USER', 'COMMON_USER']`.

What you should do is transform the Java array into a JSON string in the controller, and then use this JSON string inside the JavaScript code:

```
showAuthorityOverlay(${jsonString})
```

Comment: Mmm yeah, that could be a possible solution. Let me check. Wouldn't i be able to use something like this too? '[ADMIN_USER], [COMMON_USER]' ? Thanks for replying

Comment: I ended up doing what you said. Passing a Json String to the VIEW from the Controller. Quite better. :D Thanks pal!

Comment: To answer your comment question: that wouldn't create an array of two strings, but a single string containing brackets and a comma. Quite different.